# AR Quicklook Custom Banner or Buy Button

Tags: mobile-safari, arkit, arquicklook

Does anyone have a working link for a [AR QuickLook Buy Button or Custom Banner?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_an_apple_pay_button_or_a_custom_action_in_ar_quick_look)  example?

Is there a way to debug why the custom banner doesn't show up at all?

I've tried just appending `#applePayButtonType=plain` to my working https usdz link... but no buy button shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to pass all the parameters through the api to get the button displayed.

applePayButtonType
checkoutTitle
checkoutSubtitle
price

You can read more here:

https://applepaydemo.apple.com/ar-quick-look